# Java bitcoinj: equals override for LazyECPoint, how should it be done?

Tags: bitcoinj

In a drive to improve performance, the `bitcoinj` library defines the class `LazyECPoint` whose instances are `ECPoint` which may not have yet been initialized. Hence because an `ECPoint` (say `point`) is essentially the same thing as its lazy counterpart (say `lazy`), the library feels a call to `lazy.equals(point)` should return `true`. However, a call to `point.equals(lazy)` still returns `false`, and in fact, if point is viewed as an `Object same = point`, then `lazy.equals(same)` is now `false`. My personal gut feeling is that the library should not be the way it is. I was wondering if a professional developer would care to comment as to what the proper way to deal with this situation is. Is it worth attempting to compare `ECPoint`'s and `LazyECPoint`'s, and if so is it worth adding the complexity to the code so as to remove the sort of quirks I have mentioned? (In fact, `ECPoint` is not a `bitcoinj` class, it is part of the crypto library `spongycastle` so I can't even see how to set things straight, without changing `spongycastle`'s code). I attach a code snippet:

```
import org.bitcoinj.core.ECKey;
import org.bitcoinj.crypto.LazyECPoint;
import org.spongycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    ECKey key = new ECKey();                    // some random (compressed) key
    ECPoint point = key.getPubKeyPoint();       // associated ECPoint
    LazyECPoint lazy = new LazyECPoint(point);  // same, but different type

    System.out.println(lazy.equals(point));     // true 
    System.out.println(point.equals(lazy));     // false, equality not symmetric

    Object same = point;
    System.out.println(lazy.equals(same));     // false ...

   }
 }
```